# Delete 2D unique elements in a 2D NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I generate a set of unique coordinate combinations by using:

```
axis_1 = np.arange(image.shape[0])
axis_1 = np.reshape(axis_1,(axis_1.shape[0],1))

axis_2 = np.arange(image.shape[1])
axis_2 = np.reshape(axis_2,(axis_2.shape[0],1))


coordinates = np.array(np.meshgrid(axis_1, axis_2)).T.reshape(-1,2)
```

I then check for some condition and if it is satisfied i want to delete the coordinates from the array.
Something like this:

```
if image[coordinates[i,0], coordinates[i,1]] != 0:
    remove coordinates i from coordinates
```

I tried the remove and delete commands but one doesn't work for arrays and the other simply just removes every instance where coordinates[i,0] and coordinates[i,1] appear, rather than the unique combination of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to generate the coordinate pairs that should be removed, and `np.unique` combined with masking to remove them:

```
y, x = np.where(image > 0.7)
yx = np.column_stack((y, x))
combo = np.vstack((coordinates, yx))
unique, counts = np.unique(combo, axis=0, return_counts=True)
clean_coords = unique[counts == 1]
```

The idea here is to stack the original coordinates and the coordinates-to-be-removed in the same array, then drop the ones that occur in both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [numpy.delete](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) function, but this function returns a new modified array, and does not modify the array in-place (which would be quite problematic, specially in a `for` loop).

So your code would look like that:

```
nb_rows_deleted = 0
for i in range(0, coordinates.shape[0]):
    corrected_i = i - nb_rows_deleted
    if image[coordinates[corrected_i, 0], coordinates[corrected_i, 1]] != 0:
        coordinates = np.delete(coordinates, corrected_i, 0)
        nb_rows_deleted += 1
```

The `corrected_i` takes into consideration that some rows have been deleted during your loop.

Comment: thank you, that would work, but i would like to delete it by value, not by index ideally.

Comment: In the fourth line you can add your value condition.